# What is the best way to use a trained LibSVM model inside a Java application?

Tags: java, matlab, svm, libsvm

I have a trained LibSVM model which I want to use as a part of a Java application. I am thinking of two potentially possible ways for doing that.

1. Extracting the classification decision formula, if it is possible, and re-implement them inside the Java application.
2. I wonder if there is a Java library through which trained LibSVM models can be used. If there is not, I think such a library will be a good idea, no?

Any idea of how I can do this will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current LIBSVM package includes Java version (both JAR and source codes) directly. Please refer to the `Interfaces and extensions to LIBSVM` section in the [LIBSVM Official website](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/). Since it is maintained by LIBSVM authors at National Taiwan University, the version is latest so this should be the best package to use.

Specifically, after downloading the [latest version of LIBSVM Package (3.20)](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/cgi-bin/libsvm.cgi?%20http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm%20zip) and extracting it, use `libsvm-3.20/java/svm_predict.java` to load your trained model and predict test instances.

Comment: How about using it outside, and independently from, the LIBSVM package? I do not want my code to rely on LIBSVM.

Comment: @PatternRecognition Do you mean using LIBSVM JAR, or even without using the JAR?

Comment: Yes, I do not even want to use the LibSVM JAR, if possible?

Comment: @PatternRecognition Of course you can try to parse the model file and reconstruct classifier by yourself (please refer to http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f402). However, this is in general *not* recommended - rebuilding the wheel is not necessary and error-prone, and also when LIBSVM updates / patches your code won't be up-to-date. What would be the reason not to use "official" source codes and JAR?

Comment: You have just convinced me to use LibSVM jar. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PatternRecognition Thanks a lot :-)